# Two names of one concept?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In many disciplines we can find some confusing concepts and most of the time they are actually of the same definition and they are just talking about the same thing. For instance relative entropy is equivalent(equivalent or equivalence seems inappropriate because they relaxes the restriction to some extent, and most likely two equivalent stuff are of different nature. For example we can say EverNote is equivalent to OneNote but they are different apps but are equivalence in serving the same function) to Kullback–Leibler divergence and Most Probable Explanation is also named(kind of informal) Maximum a Posteriori and etc. Do we have a formal name for such naming or cases?

For example:

> MPE and MAP are `***`(a noun)
>   MPE is `***`(an ajdactive and a prenoun) MAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formal term for words or phrases that have the same meaning is  '[synonym](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/synonym)'. As an adjective, we could say 'MPE is synonymous to MAP'.

Comment: Maybe more specific and formal name?

Comment: Thanks and credit to @JamesK for the edit.